# remove non-letters from tokens in python lists

Tags: python, python-2.7

My data are in lists. I tokenized the data. The data contains non-letters (e.g., ?, ., !).

I would like to remove non-letters (e.g., ?, ., !) from lists below.

```
[['comfortable',
  'questions?',
  'menu',
  'items!',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there,',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies.'],
 ['.',
  'sure',
  'giving',
  'wheat',
  'fiction',
  'free',
  'foodthis',
  'place',
  'clean.']]
```

The output should look like this:

```
[['comfortable',
  'questions',
  'menu',
  'items',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there,',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies'],
 ['sure',
  'giving',
  'wheat',
  'fiction',
  'free',
  'foodthis',
  'place',
  'clean']]
```

I tried the codes below (not working):

```
import re 
tokens = [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in texts]
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: import re

tokens = [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in texts]

Comment: The above codes are not working.

Comment: You should update the attempts in the question and what result you got in that, etc.

Comment: Are all "letters" ascii?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your regex method would not work, because what you have is a list of list, and as such you are trying to pass inner list to `re.sub` .

You should iterate over the inner list as well and then use your `re.sub` . Example -

```
>>> tokens = [[y for y in (re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in sublst) if y] for sublst in texts]
>>> pprint.pprint(tokens)
[['comfortable',
  'questions',
  'menu',
  'items',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies'],
 ['sure', 'giving', 'wheat', 'fiction', 'free', 'foodthis', 'place', 'clean']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost there, your tokens are a list of lists but your list comprehension is only looking at elements of the first list.

```
from pprint import pprint

import re

tokens = [['comfortable',
           'questions?',
           'menu',
           'items!',
           'time',
           'lived',
           'there,',
           'could',
           'easily',
           'direct',
           'people',
           'appropriate',
           'menu',
           'choices',
           'given',
           'allergies.'],
          ['.',
           'sure',
           'giving',
           'wheat',
           'fiction',
           'free',
           'foodthis',
           'place',
           'clean.']]

out = [list(filter(None, [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in y])) for y in
       tokens]

pprint(out)
```

produces:

```
[['comfortable',
  'questions',
  'menu',
  'items',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies'],
 ['sure',
  'giving',
  'wheat',
  'fiction',
  'free',
  'foodthis',
  'place',
  'clean']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is always at the end you can `str.rstrip` the punctuation:

```
from string import punctuation

for sub in l:
    sub[:] = (word for word in (w.rstrip(punctuation) for w in sub)
             if word)
```

Output:

```
from pprint import pprint    as pp
pp(l)


 [['comfortable',
  'questions',
  'menu',
  'items',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies'],
 ['sure', 'giving', 'wheat', 'fiction', 'free', 'foodthis', 'place', 'clean']]
```

Or use `str.translate` to remove from anywhere:

```
from string import punctuation

for sub in l:
    sub[:] = (word for word in (w.translate(None, punctuation) for w in sub) 
             if word)
```

Output:

```
[['comfortable',
  'questions',
  'menu',
  'items',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies'],
 ['sure', 'giving', 'wheat', 'fiction', 'free', 'foodthis', 'place', 'clean']]
```

If you want a new list:

```
cleaned = [word for sub in l
           for word in (w.translate(None, punctuation)
                        for w in sub) if word]
```

translate is much more efficient than a regex, if the punctuation is at the end `rstrip` is more efficient again:

```
 In [2]: %%timeit
   ....: r = re.compile(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+')
   ....: [[y for y in (r.sub('', x) for x in sublst) if y] for sublst in l]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.3 µs per loop

In [3]: %%timeit
   ....: out = [list(filter(None, [re.sub(r'[^A-Za-z0-9]+', '', x) for x in y])) for y in
   ....:        l]
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 58.3 µs per loop

In [4]: from string import punctuation

In [5]: %%timeit
   ...: cleaned = [word for sub in l
   ...:            for word in (w.translate(None, punctuation)
   ...:                         for w in sub) if word]
   ...: 

100000 loops, best of 3: 11.6 µs per loop

In [6]: %%timeit
  ...: cleaned = [word for sub in l
   ...:            for word in (w.rstrip(punctuation)
   ...:                         for w in sub) if word]
   ...: 

100000 loops, best of 3: 6.81 µs per loop
In [7]: %%timeit
result = []                    
for d in l:                                                       
    for r in string.punctuation:
        d = [x.replace(r, '') for x in d]
    result.append([x for x in d if d])
   ....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 160 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_lst = []
for inner in lst:
    new_inner = []
    for word in inner:
        filtered = ''.join([filter(str.isalpha,  c) for c in word])
        if len(filtered) > 0:
            new_inner.append(filtered)
    new_lst.append(new_inner)
print new_lst
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import string

data = [['comfortable',
  'questions?',
  'menu',
  'items!',
  'time',
  'lived',
  'there,',
  'could',
  'easily',
  'direct',
  'people',
  'appropriate',
  'menu',
  'choices',
  'given',
  'allergies.'],
 ['.',
  'sure',
  'giving',
  'wheat',
  'fiction',
  'free',
  'foodthis',
  'place',
  'clean.']]

result = []
for d in data:
    for r in string.punctuation:
        d = [x.replace(r, '') for x in d]
    result.append([x for x in d if d])
print result
```